# There are 11 objects in this array. so why is .map() returning 12?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

I have a big json file that returns a big array of apps. there are 11 apps. but when I map over everything and print the results I get the 11 apps plus an empty object. at first I was trying to pull data from an object nestled in an object but I kept getting errors. I assumed it was because I didn't want to code something like `props.apps[0].customData, props.apps[1].customData, etc.`.

but upon further inspection in the console I found I was printing the 11 apps plus 1 empty object. since the empty object does not have any properties, it throws an error. I'm not sure if I should be using `.map()` or `.filter()` or what but I figure the first priority is figuring out why a list of 11 objects returns 12 items. I think it might have something to do with passing the apps down to the App component using props.

when I print the apps from inside the MostPopularApps.js file where they're mapped I get 11 objects plus an error that says `each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop`. when I print to the console from the App.js component I get 11 correct objects and 1 empty one. I'm now thinking the error is related to the nonexistent 12th app and its nonexistent key. any ideas?

[image: here's all the console output info]
[image: here's what an object looks like]

here's the code that maps the most popular apps

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';


const MostPopularApps = (props) => (
    <div>
        {console.log('printing inside most popular apps')}
        
        {Object.values(props.apps).map((app) => {
            console.log(app)
            // prints 11 times here
            // also throws an error that says each child needs its own unique key prop
            // so maybe there's 12 here
            return <App key={app.id} {...app} />
        })}
        <p>MOST POPULAR APPS</p>
        <App />
    </div>
)

export default MostPopularApps;
// also tried props.apps.map((app)
```

here's the code for the app component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const App = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    // prints 11 objects plus a 12th empty object
    return (
        <div>
            <Link to={`/details/:safeName`} className="featured-grid-item-badge">
                <div className="featured-grid-item">
                    <img className="featured-appIcon" />
                    <div>
                        <p className="featuredTitle">name</p>
                        <div>
                            <p className="featuredSummary">summary</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Link>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

edit: as @blex pointed out I had an empty `<App />` underneath my `<p>MOST POPULAR APPS</p>` tag. forgot I don't need to use that to render my apps. thanks for pointing out the obvious!

Comment: console(Object.values(props.apps).length) gives what?

Comment: You need to `.filter` out the empty object before `.map` or handle the empty object in the `.map` to return undefined and then filter that out.

Comment: 11 objects you want and 1 you don't is still 12.

Comment: @crashmstr where is the empty object though? I checked the call on postman and it only gives me 11 complete objects. and `{console.log(Object.values(props.apps).length)}` returns 11

Comment: @mplungjan I get 11 when I run it in MostPopularApps.js

Comment: That's pretty obvious, or am I crazy? You have an empty `<App />` below `<p>MOST POPULAR</p>`, and the `{}` in your console comes from the `console.log(props)` of that element

Comment: @blex no I'm the crazy one. thank you for pointing out the obvious. if you'd like you can make this answer its own comment and I'll mark it correct

Comment: Oh ok, glad it was that simple. Since this is a typo question, it won't help future readers. I suggest you delete this question, if you don't mind

Comment: @blex do you think I could I keep it up if I provided a better explanation of how the map works and why you don't need an empty tag or nah?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary, but that's just one guy's opinion. If you think someone may one day stumble upon your question and find a solution, sure

Answer (score 0):

There are 12 items in the array, at least per the screenshot you supplied. The last one is just an empty object with no properties.

EDIT: My original post said that the empty object is the same as undefined. As per the comment below, this is not true. It does not change however that you do in fact have 12 elements in the array.

Comment: `{}` !== `undefined`. `{}` is an object with no properties, `undefined` is no thing.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I learned something as well then. I'll edit what I posted.